# Conditional Formatting - Number stored as text

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to use VBA to add conditional formatting to a column, so that when the cell value not equal to a reference value, fill the cell with yellow color.

```
' c represent the column number, lRow represent the last row
' RefVal is a string variable read from reference spreadsheet

Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lRow, c)).FormatConditions. _
    Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, RefVal).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

After running the code, the condition rule is as below:
[image]

What I really want is below (note the quotes around `183957`):
[image]

It was because the cells I'm working on are "number stored as text".  If I use the first condition rule, it will always be "true".  Only the second rule can do the real compare.

[image]

How shall I solve this problem?  I have no control of the spreadsheet contents.  How shall I compare "text to text" vs. "text to number"?  Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Format the cells as number `Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0"`

Comment: I have no control of the cells.  I just want to compare all cells in "text mode".  How shall I do that?  Thanks!

Comment: You could try conditional formatting for specific text _ Not Containing

Answer (score 1):

You can do that entirely in VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, RefVal As String 'maybe other appropriate datatype
    RefVal = Worksheets("ReferenceSheetNameHere!").Cells(1, 1).Value 'in Cells, specify coordinates of a cell with reference value!
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> RefVal Then
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that (as mentioned in comments in code) you have to specify where your reference value is located.

This method with this signature handles worksheet change event including cell change, so it mimics autofilter, but is more powerful.

In order to make it work, this code should be pasted in VBA file corresponding to sheet you want to handle, i.e. when you open VBA editor, on the left side in the tree you should select the sheet.

Comment: Michal, thank you for your input.  However, the reference value I need to compare is a variable, which read from another reference spreadsheet.  so I cannot just use the string "183957" in VBA.  I need to use a variable like RefVal.

Comment: Then just declare it, like: `Dim compareValue As Variant`, you can use other appropriate datatype and assign value to it and use this variable: `If Cells(i, 1).Value <> compareValue Then`

Comment: Then we back to the original problem - I want to add conditional formatting to cells.  I thought I should use the xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, compareValue condition.  However, due to data type mismatch, this condition will always be true because a string is not equal to a number.  So my question is - what is the best way to achieve this with conditional formatting?

Comment: How are we back to original problem? I don't understand you. I provided you full solution. Your further remarks have nothing in common with my answer. Do you even understand my answer?

Comment: Your solution is "If Cells(i, 1).Value <> compareValue Then".  How do I use VBA code to put this solution into a cell's conditional formatting?

Comment: I'm sorry.  But the business requirement is to set the conditional formatting in the cells.  So when the end user entering data, it will change format in realtime.  I appreciate you help.

Comment: @Helloguys I edited answer and it should now solve your problem.